# How to check if android system update is currently downloading in background?

Tags: java, android, notifications, operating-system

How do I query the android system in order to check the current status of download/installation of a system update?

Background: Our users are occassionally removing the battery/powering off device while in the middle of a download/os update. They cannot tell because of us running a limited view within our custom launcher/apps. We need a way to check the status and warn user if update happening

Comment: I do not recall seeing an API for this, though I may be forgetting one. If this is your own custom firmware, you are in control of system update timing, so you could create your own API for this.